# React.js - Preventing Multiple Image Uploads on File Input Change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, firebase-storage

I'm working on a React.js application that allows users to send messages with text and images. I have an input field for text and a hidden file input field for selecting images. The issue I'm facing is that when I select an image, it gets uploaded twice, even though I intend to send it only once. How can I prevent this double upload behavior?

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from "react";
// ... (other imports and context setup) ...

const Input = () => {
  const [text, setText] = useState("");
  const [img, setImg] = useState(null);

  // ... (context and user data setup) ...

  const handleSend = async () => {
    if (img) {
      const storageRef = ref(storage, uuid());

      const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, img);

      uploadTask.on(
        (error) => {
          console.log(error);
        },
        () => {
          getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then(async (downloadURL) => {
            await updateDoc(doc(db, "chats", data.chatId), {
              messages: arrayUnion({
                id: uuid(),
                senderId: currentUser.uid,
                date: Timestamp.now(),
                img: downloadURL,
              }),
            });
          });
        }
      );
    } else {
      // ... (text message handling) ...
    }

    // ... (update database and reset input fields) ...
  };

  return (
    <div className="input">
      <input
        disabled={isDisabled}
        type="text"
        placeholder="Type something..."
        onChange={(e) => setText(e.target.value)}
        value={text}
      />
      <div className="send">
        <label htmlFor="file">
          <img src="https://img.icons8.com/fluency/48/image--v1.png" alt="" />
          <input
            disabled={isDisabled}
            type="file"
            style={{ display: "none" }}
            id="file"
            onChange={(e) => setImg(e.target.files[0])}
          />
        </label>
        <button onClick={handleSend}>Send</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );

  // ... (export and additional details) ...
};
```

I suspect that the onChange event for the file input might be triggering twice, causing the image to be uploaded twice. How can I resolve this issue and ensure that the image is uploaded only once when I select it?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.